# Driving an Italian registered motorcycle in Denmark as a resident

Tags: eu, eu-citizens, citizenship, driving, vehicle-registration

I moved to Denmark for a job 3 months ago. I am planning to bring my motorcycle (registered in Italy) to Denmark. As a resident in Denmark, I know I have to register it within 2 weeks.

If police stops me, how can I prove that I arrived (with motorcycle) during the last 2 weeks and avoid a fine? Of course, I do not want to get a fine.

In general, what is the punishment for a resident in Denmark when driving a vehicle with foreign plates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find many details on this 14-day rule but all the sources I found, including [the EU website](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/registration/taxes/denmark/index_en.htm) suggest that it only applies to people who are just moving into the country. So it means you must register the car/motorcycle within 14 days **of becoming a resident**, and not 14 days of importing the vehicle. Basically, it seems it's intended to cover a car you would use to move into the country.

Proving that you only registered as a resident in the last few days would seem relatively easy but of course that's not your case. Nobody is expected to prove they brought a car/motorcycle into the country recently even though they already were a resident because in this case another procedure applies.

Once you are a resident, you cannot drive a foreign-registered car in the country without declaring it first, even for a single day. SKAT, the Danish tax authority has a web page on the procedure to follow when [importing a foreign-registered vehicle as a Danish resident](http://www.skat.dk/SKAT.aspx?oId=2113676&vId=0&lang=US).

The first step is submitting an online form even before you bring the vehicle into the country. You need to print the receipt and to keep it in the vehicle. That's how the police can check whether you are currently importing the vehicle and waiting for the inspection/paperwork or driving it illegally.

Comment: Ok, now it definitely makes sense! Thanks. Just for personal knowledge, what about if driving a foreign registered vehicle in the country (as a resident)? There will be a fine or they will take the vehicle? Is there any EU law about this or every country decides the punishment (examples?)?

Comment: @top_broker I think it's up to each country. I would expect a fine, but I don't really know.

Comment: According to [this tax advice page](https://tax.dk/jv/ac/A_C_3_2_1_8_4.htm), the penalty is a fine, or up to 1 year and 6 months prison when there is intent to avoid the registration fee, or up to 8 years in aggravated cases. [Here is a case from 2012](https://www.skat.dk/SKAT.aspx?oID=2113077) where someone received a 20 day suspended sentence and a 56,000 kr fine.